# Where does the response "Anytime" come from?

Tags: etymology, history, origin-unknown

When someone says "Thank you" whenever I have helped them out, I naturally respond with "Anytime". I recently started thinking about this and couldn't quite figure out where this word originates from. So I thought I would see if I could find anything online, but found little or nothing to do with this.

So, where does the word/phrase "Anytime" come from when giving a response to "Thank you"'s?

Comment: Anytime: one-word form by 1854, from any + time.(n.).http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=anytime

Comment: And hence general reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it really means, "You can ask for my help anytime," because we normally say "Thank you" after being helped by others. 
So we just say "Anytime!" meaning we are ready to help you anytime. :)